# Getters and Setters in Android

Tags: java, android

please help me... i don't know what i'm doing wrong!!

I have 3 classes.

1 - Activity = TelaCadastroRestaurant.java

2 - Entity = Restaurant.java

3 - Method's Class = Metodos.java

Problem: When i call **getNomeRestaurante()** in method **callMandarNuvem()** or in **ANY** other method **BUT** **pegarvalores()**, **it DOESN'T WORK**... it shows null.

Error's print: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Bsk.png

********************EXAMPLE***************************

If i create a Restaurant object INSIDE the method pegarValores() and in a Toast, call: getNomeRestaurante()... IT IS ALL NORMAL.

but, if i create a Restaurant object OUTSIDE the method pegarValores() and in a Toast, call: getNomeRestaurante()... IT SHOWS NULL.

*********************METHOD'S MEANING*******************

method -> inicializaComponentes(): it references the components of Activity.

method -> acaoBotoes(): it deal with the clicks on buttons

method -> pegarValores(): it means, catching values.

method -> mandarNuvem(): it means, send to clound (save)

method -> caixaCerteza(): it means, you sure you wanna do that?

method -> taskInProgress(): it means, loading..wait

---

public class TelaCadastroRestaurante extends Activity {

```
private Button proximoButton;
private EditText nomeRestauranteEditText, emailRestauranteEditText, telefoneRestauranteEditText;

private String nomeRestauranteValores, emailRestauranteValores;
private int telefoneRestauranteValores;

private String voceTemCerteza = "Você tem certeza que deseja cadastrar o restaurante ";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro_restaurante);
    incializarComponentes();
    acaoBotoes();
}

public void incializarComponentes() {
    nomeRestauranteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextNomeRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    emailRestauranteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    telefoneRestauranteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefoneRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
    proximoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProximoTelaCadastroRestaurante);
}

public void acaoBotoes() {
    proximoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pegarValores();
            callMandarNuvem();
        }
    });
}

public void pegarValores(){
    Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();

    nomeRestauranteValores = nomeRestauranteEditText.getText().toString();
    emailRestauranteValores = emailRestauranteEditText.getText().toString();
    telefoneRestauranteValores = Integer.parseInt(telefoneRestauranteEditText.getText().toString());

    rest.setNomeRest(nomeRestauranteValores);
    rest.setEmailRest(emailRestauranteValores);
    rest.setTelefoneRest(telefoneRestauranteValores);

}

public void callMandarNuvem(){
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Metodos.mandarNuvem(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this);
        }
    };

    Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();
    Metodos.caixaCerteza(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this, voceTemCerteza + rest.getNomeRest() + "?",r);

}
```

}

---

public class Restaurante {

```
private String idRest;
private String nomeRest;
private String emailRest;
private int telefoneRest;

public Restaurante() {
}

public Restaurante(String nomeRest, String emailRest, int telefoneRest) {
    this.nomeRest = nomeRest;
    this.emailRest = emailRest;
    this.telefoneRest = telefoneRest;
}

public String getIdRest() {
    return idRest;
}

public void setIdRest(String idRest) {
    this.idRest = idRest;
}

public String getNomeRest() {
    return nomeRest;
}

public void setNomeRest(String nomeRest) {
    this.nomeRest = nomeRest;
}

public String getEmailRest() {
    return emailRest;
}

public void setEmailRest(String emailRest) {
    this.emailRest = emailRest;
}

public int getTelefoneRest() {
    return telefoneRest;
}

public void setTelefoneRest(int telefoneRest) {
    this.telefoneRest = telefoneRest;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return nomeRest;
}
```

}

---

public class Metodos {

```
private static ProgressDialog dialog;

// Metodo que mostra o Aguarde a verificação
public static void taskInProgres(boolean mostrar, Context context) {

    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "","Espere um momento...", true);
    }
    if (mostrar) {
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}

// Metodo que mostra a caixa de certeza
public static void caixaCerteza(final Context context, final String texto, final Runnable func) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builderaction = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builderaction.setTitle("Atenção!");
    builderaction.setMessage(texto);

    builderaction.setPositiveButton("Sim",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    func.run();
                }
            });
    builderaction.setNegativeButton("Não",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builderaction.create();
    alert.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_stop);
    alert.show();
}

// Metodo que manda pra nuvem
public static void mandarNuvem(final Context context){

    Metodos.taskInProgres(true, context);

        Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();

        ParseObject restauranteParse = new ParseObject("Restaurante");
        restauranteParse.put("nomeRestaurante", rest.getNomeRest());
        restauranteParse.put("emailRestaurante", rest.getEmailRest());
        restauranteParse.put("telefoneRestaurante", rest.getTelefoneRest());
        restauranteParse.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Metodos.taskInProgres(false, context);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

}

Comment: Please correct code formatting in your post. And can you ask a clear question?

Comment: @kenorb, i'm sorry, but i dont know how to be more specific... and how am i supposed to correct my post? whats wrong with it?

Comment: Getters and setters in Android work like in normal Java, there's no difference. If they return `null`, then that's the value set on the class.

Comment: Not an answer, but you need to do some learning until you understand why this, `Metodos.mandarNuvem(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this);`, is very bad.  Never pass a context to anything static. You cannot treat activities like POJOs.

Comment: @Simon I don't think there's any problem passing a Context to a static method. Problem would be if you hold a static reference to the Context.

Comment: @Simon
hm... but i did this beacuse organization... look what i'm thinking: if i create a method X and pass a method A to its, it will work fine. But if i want to create a method AA with a little bit modifications compared to method A... if i dont do it  my way, i'm gonna have to create a method Y and create a method AA. But doing my way, i'm gonna have the method X and just the method A and AA... i won't need the method Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new instance of `Restaurant` and not setting any values. I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 public class TelaCadastroRestaurante extends Activity {

   private Button proximoButton;
   private EditText nomeRestauranteEditText, emailRestauranteEditText, telefoneRestauranteEditText;

   private String nomeRestauranteValores, emailRestauranteValores;
   private int telefoneRestauranteValores;

   private String voceTemCerteza = "Você tem certeza que deseja cadastrar o restaurante ";

   private final Restaurante rest;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_tela_cadastro_restaurante);
     incializarComponentes();
     acaoBotoes();
        }

    public void incializarComponentes() {
     nomeRestauranteEditText = (EditText)                   findViewById(R.id.editTextNomeRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
     emailRestauranteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmailRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
      telefoneRestauranteEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTelefoneRestauranteTelaCadastroRestaurante);
      proximoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonProximoTelaCadastroRestaurante);
   }

  public void acaoBotoes() {
   proximoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pegarValores();
        callMandarNuvem();
    }
});
}

  public void pegarValores(){
     rest = new Restaurante();

   nomeRestauranteValores =       nomeRestauranteEditText.getText().toString();
   emailRestauranteValores = emailRestauranteEditText.getText().toString();
   telefoneRestauranteValores = Integer.parseInt(telefoneRestauranteEditText.getText().toString());

   rest.setNomeRest(nomeRestauranteValores);
   rest.setEmailRest(emailRestauranteValores);
   rest.setTelefoneRest(telefoneRestauranteValores);

  }

  public void callMandarNuvem(){
     Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Metodos.mandarNuvem(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this);
    }
};

   Metodos.caixaCerteza(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this, voceTemCerteza + rest.getNomeRest() + "?",r);
```

}

In your `Metodos` class, change `mandarNuvem` to:

```
// Metodo que manda pra nuvem
public static void mandarNuvem(final Context context,Restaurante rest){

Metodos.taskInProgres(true, context);

    ParseObject restauranteParse = new ParseObject("Restaurante");
    restauranteParse.put("nomeRestaurante", rest.getNomeRest());
    restauranteParse.put("emailRestaurante", rest.getEmailRest());
    restauranteParse.put("telefoneRestaurante", rest.getTelefoneRest());
    restauranteParse.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Salvo com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Metodos.taskInProgres(false, context);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

And then change your call to the method to:

```
 public void callMandarNuvem(){
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Metodos.mandarNuvem(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this,rest);
    }
};
```

Comment: do i need create an external Restaurant object in the class metodos to?

Comment: Don't see why, since in `Metodos` you only use it locally in the `mandarNuvem` method.

Comment: Yeah, i agree with u....
But, it almost done.. :D
I only have this error:
http://i.imgur.com/CV8oewg.png

Comment: Updated my answer. Check that

Comment: Damnnn, it worked perfectly, i got it what u done, but i don't know why... and another question: in your opinion, did a write something wrong to get a negative vote?

Comment: The point is: your question isn't related to `getters` and `setters`. Do you undersdant it now?

Comment: hummm, so you think should i change the names to..?? Do you have any idea? @vinitius

Comment: Just leave it like this, because it was the way you understood when you asked the question. The important thing is if you were able to solve the problem and, most important, if you understood and learned the real problem and what to do in order to solve it :)

Comment: humm, got you... it would be much better if world only have people like you.. at least, seeing i did dumb thing, you helped me.. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Restaurante rest = new Restaurante();
Metodos.caixaCerteza(TelaCadastroRestaurante.this, voceTemCerteza + rest.getNomeRest() + "?",r);
```

you are calling the default Constructor of your Entity-Class to build an "empty" Restaurant. So the String nomeRest keeps its value which is null at that point.

So rather call the other Constructor where you pass your values or use the setters like you do in the other method!

Comment: i got it what you are saying, but the problem is: I'm going to be using getNomeRest and other getters all the time, and if i use getters and setters, it gets easier....